# list all downloaded packages - repotrack / rpm

Tags: shell, rpm

I am downloading packages using `repotrack`, doing something like this -

`repotrack -a x86_64 -p $PACKAGE_LOCATION/Packages $pckg`

where it gets $pckg from a text file. Now I want to verify signatures of all packages (and dependencies) before installing.

`rpm --checksig <package_name>`

Here I need package_name of all packages and dependencies downloaded. One way to do this will be `ls` over `$PACKAGE_LOCATION/Packages` location. But I am using bash script and looping over `ls` content is fragile. Other mechanism I thought of trying is using `rpm -qa` but this queries all installed (and not downloaded) packages.

Is there anything I can do to get list of all downloaded packages.

Answer (score 0):

Hope if you are looking for what package you have installed that use below command.

`rpm -qa | grep packagename`

As well as you can use `rpm --help` to get more flags info.
hope it will help...!!!

Comment: no, as I mentioned in the question, I am looking for packages downloaded (and not installed yet).